# I'm looking for a succinct way of writing 4 combinations of the same information without simply listing them

Tags: grammar, phrases

I'm practicing for my exams and I've reached a study in which a scuba diver:

- Learnt information on land, then tried to recall it underwater
- Learnt information underwater, then tried to recall it on land
- Learnt information on land and tried to recall on land
- Learnt information underwater and tried to recall underwater

I don't want to simply list those four combinations one after another, because it goes on for way too long. I'm sure there's a nice, succinct way to convey that they did all 4 combinations of the two situations (land and underwater).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Like: Learned information on land and underwater, and then tried to recall this information on land and underwater? Or does it need to explicitly list each combination?

Comment: It's more that it needs to specify that as well as learning in different places, it was also tested in the same places

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We are not here to provide writing advice, though we can help if you have a problem with a specific point of grammar or usage. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of the kinds of questions we can answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are listing every possible combination, I would argue it suffices to say:

> Learned and recalled information both underwater and on land.

*Note: learned, not learnt.*

You could list them all, but then you, well, need to list them all... And unless there is a particular reason to do so, it seems unnecessarily verbose.

A slightly more verbose version:

> Learned information both underwater and on land, and recalled it both underwater and on land.

But again, I think the repetition is not needed to be understood.

Comment: I used to write technical documentation and personally  I would have used your second form. A surprising number of people don't digest what they read and wouldn't absorb the full meaning of the first.

Answer (score 1):

For some purposes, a table would be more clear, with presented location in columns, recalled location in rows:

```
REC \ PRES    On Land    Underwater
On Land         YES         YES
Under Water     YES         YES
```

Comment: It seems off topic to respond with tabular data, in my opinion. I'm not saying that your suggestion isn't easy to read (it is, especially if only a subset of combinations are true); but that's beside the point. A table would still need some sort of written explanation, and it's this explanation that OP is struggling with.

Comment: Fair enough. But for written documents, the table might help the reader visualize what the sentence says.